# Run Excel VBA code from newly created Excel file using Python

Tags: python, excel, vba, win32com, abaqus

I am trying to run Excel macros from ABAQUS software tool which has inbuilt Python.

I have a default Excel file, I want this as a main Excel file and to make a new Excel file depending on the output database file.

- I access the ABAQUS output data base file and get its name and make a new Excel file named by combining the output data base file name plus some other name.
- I copy the main Excel file to this new Excel file.

I am able to open this newly created file, but I am unable to run the macros.

Here is the code with comments.

I get the path of my file with name and extension

```
filePath = odbFile.path
```

Filename with extension only

```
filename_w_ext = os.path.basename(filePath)
odbfilename,odbfileExtension = os.path.splitext(filename_w_ext)
excel_filename='abc.xlsm' 
odbfilename+'_FAT'+'.xlsm'
newExcelFile = odbfilename+'_FAT'+'.xlsm' 
shutil.copy(excel_filename, newExcelFile)
```

I access the win32client to access the Excel application

```
xl = win32com.client.Dispatch("Excel.Application")
```

Opening the Excel file, give the file path

```
xl.Workbooks.Open(newExcelFile)
```

Say newExcelFile created name is `new.xlsm`.

To run the Excel macros using PYTHON, the default code is

```
xl.Application.Run("excelName!ModuleNumberOfTheMacro.MacroName")
```

Run my macro to import nodes from Excel

```
xl.Application.Run("newExcelFile!Module1.ImporterFichiersTextes")
```

I put down the same format but Python is looking for the Excel sheet 'newExcelFile', instead of `new.xlsm`.